# this.value comes up as undefind when function is called from onchange event

Tags: javascript

```
<select id="dropdown1" name="dropdown1" onchange="dropdown1_onchange();">
        <option selected value=""> Select</option>
        <option value="value1">value1</option>
        <option value="value2">value2</option>
        <option value="value3">value3</option>
</select>


function dropdown1_onchange()
{
    alert(this.value);
}
```

Javascript gets called but this.value comes up undefined. I know I can use

> $('dropdown1').value

but I am trying to understand why `this` sometimes represents a current object and other times - window. Normally when I use inline javascript `this` is a representation of the current object...

Comment: Did you mean `dropdown1_onchange.call(this)`?

Comment: You're passing the current element (`this` in the handler) as an argument. Your function doesn't have any parameters. Use one.

Comment: Don't use event handler content attributes. Use event handler IDL attributes or event listeners.

Comment: try `function dropdown1_onchange(context){alert(context.value);}`

Comment: Bergi, I just edited it, I did not pass this as a parameter before, I just put it there while tweaking my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problems is that `this` inside function `dropdown1_onchange` refers to `window`. You can use argument to retrieve value.

```
function dropdown1_onchange(elem)
{
   alert(elem.value);
}
```

Comment: even when I call the function from the element itself?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use inline javascript. Change your code to use event listeners like the following:

```
<select id="dropdown1" name="dropdown1">
        <option selected value=""> Select</option>
        <option value="value1">value1</option>
        <option value="value2">value2</option>
        <option value="value3">value3</option>
</select>
<script>
document.getElementById('dropdown1').addEventListener('click', dropdown1_onchange);
function dropdown1_onchange(event)
{
    alert(event.target.value);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
function dropdown1_onchange(el) {

    if (el.selectedIndex <= 0)
        return null;

    alert(el.options[el.selectedIndex].value);

}
```

JS Bin [here](http://jsbin.com/yakegeluru/1/edit?html,js,output).

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into the onchange event of the select element 2 ways.

**Inline**
Putting the event handler code in the Select elements onchange="" attribute. This becomes your entire event handler function. It is basically wrapped with a function call

```
<select id="dopdown1" onchange="dropdown1_change">
</select>

// EXAMPLE FUNCTION OF WHAT HAPPENS BEHIND THE SCENES.
// This function exists in the browers/javascript framework.
// Your code will be executed inside its context.
function sudo_eventhandler(event)
{
    // Whatever is inside your onchange="" attribute
    dropdown1_change(this);
}

function dropdown1_change(element)
{
    alert(element.value);
}
```

So you will have to pass `this` or any other properties to any method you call outside of this function as `this` is no longer the element.

**Event Handler**
You can hook up your own event handler to the element by selecting it out in javascript.

```
document.getElementById('dropdown1').addEventListener('click', dropdown1_onchange);

function dropdown1_change()
{
    alert(this.value);
}
```

This makes your event handler the actual handler and not just a method called from inside of the handled event. So `this` is now the element you expect as the element is essentially calling the method, not the window.